# my pyvona speak() function is not working

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, pygame, typeerror

I'm trying to use pyvona but in the speak() function this keeps happening. Here is the code:

```
def speak(self, text_to_speak):
    """Speak a given text
    """
    if not pygame_available:
        raise PyvonaException(
            "Pygame not installed. Please install to use speech.")

    with tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile() as f:
        with self.use_ogg_codec():
            self.fetch_voice_fp(text_to_speak, f)
        f.seek(0)
        if not pygame.mixer.get_init():
            pygame.mixer.init()
        channel = pygame.mixer.Channel(5)
        sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(f)
        channel.play(sound)
        while channel.get_busy():
            pass
```

and the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/noahchalifour/Desktop/pyvona-0.25/pyvona.py", line 250, in <module>
        v.speak('Hello World')
    File "/Users/noahchalifour/Desktop/pyvona-0.25/pyvona.py", line 138, in speak
        sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(f)
TypeError: Unrecognized argument (type SpooledTemporaryFile)
```

Comment: What version of pygame are you using?

Comment: works fine for me, how did you install pygame and pyvona?

Comment: im using pygame 1.9.2

Comment: I only have this problem on my macbook, it works fine on ubuntu. Maybe it's one of the things el captain broke again

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(file=f)
```

or

```
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(file=f._file)
```

If the file is a **sound file** it should work.

Answer (score 0):

After having similar issues with pygame,  I moved to pyglet, try:

```
Import pyglet
music = pyglet.media.load('file.mp3')
music.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```